# The MVVM tag on Stack Overflow looks like MWM

Tags: support, tags, user-interface

[image]

I know this is due to the type face, but I think we need a bit more space between the two “v”.  (I am using IE 8 and I don’t know how it looks in other browsers.)

---

I don't think anything complex is needed, just setting the letter spacing to be a big larger in the CSS should do the job.

Comment: I see what you mean, but how do you propose to implement this? Actually adding a space would just break the tag into the `[mv]` and `[vm]` tags, which is even worse.

Comment: The characters are close to each other. [m] looks like [rn]. Which can be embarising viewing the [pom] tag.  But you get used to it.

Comment: @Pop `letter-spacing`?

Comment: @Pop maybe letter spacing, or a different typeface, it looks ok in the "drop down menu"

Comment: Arial is such a crappy font.  No distinction between uppercase i and lowercase l either.  IIllIIll

Comment: It looks okay when bold, but I agree, some letter spacing would be nice in the regular style.

Comment: `[m-v-vm]` perhaps?  That's a bit tedious to type.

Comment: @James - not if you set up `[m-v-vm]` as the main tag and `[mvvm]` as a synonym. Entering "mvvm" will get automatically converted to "m-v-vm"

Comment: @ChrisF:  Ah; a good point.  I like that then.